# Selenium Webdriver - how to click a button within a complex html table?

Tags: html, selenium, webdriver, html-table

Would anyone know how to write the locator string that would click on the Open button from the html shown below?

I tried using the id but it didn't work b/c it's common to 2 other buttons on the same page.  I laso tried this but no luck:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Open')]")).click();
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="sipButCommon globalButton" id="aF:STC5:incSTC5:st_SB9:searchR40:srsvsr_SRESULT5_0:openRecsr_SRESULT5_0container" style="margin-right:5px;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="middle">Open
                    <div class="btnstub"></div></td>
                <td class="right">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table></div>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Asking me what the error is helped me find the problem.  I wasn't getting an error b/c I left out the code that clicks the button.  I added it and the xpath locator above works.   Sorry about that, and thanks for the help.